# Using group by to Convert null to 0 or remain null

Tags: sql

My table is like this:

```
ID identity school location character percent
1  teacher  Gateways Leeds  nice 80
1  teacher  Gateways Leeds  good 20
2  student  Seva    Coventry   nice  100
2  student  Seva    Coventry   good  
3  professor Regent   London nice
3  professor Regent   London good
```

In the 1st ID, the sum of column [percent] in the same group (identity, school, location) with [nice] and [good] is 100.

In the 2nd ID, one of the cell in [percent] is provided as null, but my hope is to make it 0

In the 3rd ID, both cells are null.I do not let it convert to 0.

My problem is for 2nd and 3rd ID:

How could I set condition to let one of the cell be 0 if another cell is 100, or remain both cells as null if another cell is null?

```
ID identity school location character percent
1  teacher  Gateways Leeds  nice 80
1  teacher  Gateways Leeds  good 20
2  student  Seva    Coventry   nice  100
2  student  Seva    Coventry   good  0
3  professor Regent   London nice
3  professor Regent   London good
```

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the desired result based your sample data?

Comment: Edited. Is it clear? Thanks..

Comment: What would you do if there were non null values but they don't add up to a hundred but value greater or less than 100? It'd also help if you tagged the DBMS you're using.

Comment: So you are not doing any aggregation. Why do you mention `GROUP BY` then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way in MS SQL server.

```
 Select * into #temp  from 
( Select 1 as ID,          'teacher'  as   [identity],  'Gateways' as school,  
'Leeds'     as [Location] ,'nice' as character,  80  as [Percent]
union all Select 1 as ID,   'teacher'  as  [identity],  'Gateways' as school,  
'Leeds'     as [Location] ,'good' as character,  20  as [Percent]
 union all Select 2 as ID,   'student'  as  [identity],  'Seva'    as school ,  
'Coventry'   as [Location] ,'nice' as character, 100  as [Percent]
 union all Select 2 as ID,   'student'  as  [identity],  'Seva'    as school ,  
 'Coventry'   as [Location] ,'good' as character, null as [Percent] 
 union all Select 3 as ID,   'professor' as [identity], 'Regent'  as school ,  
 'London'       as [Location] ,'nice' as character, null as [Percent]
  union all Select 3 as ID,   'professor'as [identity], 'Regent'  as school ,  
 'London'       as [Location] ,'good' as character, null as [Percent]) z 



update  t   
set [Percent] = 0 
from 
#temp t 
 where [Percent] is null and exists (select id, [identity], school, [location], 
 sum([percent]) totalPercent from #temp t2 
                                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.[identity] = t.[identity] 
 and t2.school = t.school 
                                  and t.[Location] = t2.[Location] 
                                  group by id, [identity], school, [location] 
                                  having  sum([percent]) = 100)
```

I assumed it should be within same ID, location, identity, and school and if sum for the whole group is 100 it will update wherever there is occurrence of nulls within the group to 0.

Output:

```
Select * from #temp
```

[image]